# Filter a list inside forEach function of another list - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

I am trying to filter a list and return it inside map function of another list.

```
val userChoiceCategories = recommendedCategoryDb.find(RecommendedCategory::userId eq userId).toList()
    
    userChoiceCategories.forEach {
        //
        return articleDb.find().toList()
            .filter { article ->
                article.category != it.category.name
            }
    }

    return listOf()
```

I want to display articles from all other categories except the one user has selected
to show them in Explore page. The forEach loop only works for the first item in the list I guess and it stops. any clarifications where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you show something more complete? For one thing, `forEach` doesn't return anything. Did you mean to use `map` somewhere? You mentioned it in your question but there is no `map` used in the code you posted. And the function obviously always return an empty list.

Comment: Yes, at the end, I want to loop through all the user recommended categories, filter my articles accordingly and return them, As you may know returning from map/forEach is not the end of the function, you explicitly need to return something at the end of the function.

Comment: You probably want to use `return@forEach` inside the loop, or just omit it, a return is not necessary in `forEach`, the lambda returns Unit. Using `return` will exit the method.

Comment: @TylerV the function returns list so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin has a concept called [qualified returns](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html#return-to-labels), which means return statements inside lambdas ([like the one passed to `forEach`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html)) need to be handled differently.

**Consider the following examples.**

This will print the first name only, then exit (like your method) and return 1

```kotlin
fun printNames(names: List<String>): Int {
    names.forEach {
        println(it)
        return 1
    }
    return names.size
}
```

This will print all the names and return the list size, but the inner return is pointless

```kotlin
fun printNames(names: List<String>): Int {
    names.forEach {
        println(it)
        return@forEach
    }
    return names.size
}
```

This will also print all the names

```kotlin
fun printNames(names: List<String>): Int {
    names.forEach {
        println(it)
    }
    return names.size
}
```

This will print only the non-empty names, the `return@forEach` here acts like a `continue` in a normal for loop.

```kotlin
fun printNames(names: List<String>): Int {
    names.forEach {
        if( it.isEmpty() ) return@forEach
        println(it)
    }
    return names.size
}
```

**So how does this affect your question?**

There are two problems I see with what you have:

1. the un-qualified return that exits the loop immediately (as you noted in the question)
2. the fact that it doesn't apply the filters cumulatively ([filter](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) returns the filtered list)

It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do still, but a fixed version of the code you posted would look like this (seems to be trying to return a list of articles that do not match the user choice categories)

```kotlin
    var result = articleDb.find().toList()

    userChoiceCategories.forEach { choice ->
        //
        result = result.filter { article ->
            article.category != choice.category.name
        }
    }

    return result
```

As a more compact way of doing it, if you wanted to return articles whose category matches any of the selected categories you could do something like this (and could invert the boolean logic or use `filterNot` if you want the articles that do not match the list of categories)

```kotlin
    // find all articles whose category is in the user choice list
    return articleDb.find().toList().filter { article ->
        userChoiceCategories.any { choice ->
            article.category == choice.category.name
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
val userChoiceCategories = recommendedCategoryDb.find(RecommendedCategory::userId eq userId).toList()

val categoriesToOmit = userChoiceCategories.map { it.category.name }.toSet()

return articleDb.find().toList().filter { !categoriesToOmit.contains(it.category) }
```

and in more conciese form:

```kotlin
return recommendedCategoryDb
  .find(RecommendedCategory::userId eq userId).toList()
  .map { it.category.name }.toSet()
  .let { toOmit ->
    articleDb
      .find().toList()
      .filter { article -> article.category !in toOmit } 
  }
```